# RealmSwift List requires that String inherit from Object

Tags: swift, realm

I'm trying to have a list of Strings on `RealmSwift` like this:

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

// V1
class foo: Object {
    let strings = List<String>()
}
```

But I get this error:

> 'List' requires that 'String' inherit from 'Object'

Is anyway to create a list of Strings without creating an entire class with one String property in `Realm`?

Comment: Is that java you are using in swift? I think you need `[String]()` or `Array<String>()`

Comment: @smac89 is not java, is swift, https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#models

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Arrays of primitives are not yet supported by Realm Swift. You can subscribe to [GitHub issue 1120](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1120) to be notified when we add support. Until then you'll need to wrap the string in a class that derives from `RealmSwift.Object`.